# Indexer status (7414 in backlog)

Tags: magento2, cron, reindex, crontab

When I run indexer:status from the command line to look at the status of my indexes I notice some are like this:

```
| Catalog Product Rule | Ready  | Schedule  | working (7414 in backlog) | 2019-02-19 01:37:48 |
```

What does working xxxx in backlog mean? Is this something I should be worried about. 3 of my indexes are reporting that atm.

What table is the backlog in or where does this backlog reside? The last question// Is it safe to truncate the cron_schedule table?

Answer (score 1):

You can run these commands below:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

And install the [Magemojo cron module](https://github.com/magemojo/m2-ce-cron) to have:

- Speeds up execution of cron.
- Stops db locking.
- Prevents cron history records from exploding.
- Stops cron processes from overruning each other.
- Stops the cron from running while system is under configurable load conditions.
- Sets the max number of simultaneous cron processes.
- Sets the amount of history.